# How to install Jet OLEDB provider for .NET apps?

Tags: .net, ms-access, oledb, jet, ms-jet-ace

How is the latest `JET OLEDB` provider for `.NET` apps meant to be installed?

[This link](http://www.microsoft.com/en-my/download/details.aspx?id=13255) says that the `Microsoft Access Database Engine` is **not** to be installed in order to install the `JET OLEDB` provider.

How then should the `JET OLEDB` provider be installed if it is required for a `.NET` app?

Comment: There is no Jet Provider which is specifically for .Net.  Windows itself includes the Jet Provider; I don't understand why you want to install it again.  The problem many .Net developers encounter is that the Jet Provider is only accessible by 32-bit proccesses --- if the .Net runs as 64-bit, it can't use the Jet Provider.  And it that situation, you must use the 64-bit ACE Provider to enable OleDb access to your Access db file.  The ACE is backwards-compatible: it supports both the older MDB and new ACCDB formats for Access db files.

Comment: If a .NET app uses the `Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0` provider, will this be installed with Windows?

Comment: No the ACE is not included with Windows.  You must download and install the version you need (32 or 64 bit).

Comment: Why is JET installed with Windows and not ACE?

Comment: Jet (32-bit) became an integral part of Windows years ago, providing database services for core windows components, and it "belongs" to the "Windows group" within Microsoft. ACE "belongs" to the "Office group" and, as the ACE download page says "[it] is not intended as a general replacement for Jet"; it is much more closely tied to Office now.

Comment: I think that is a consequence of the division of responsibilities within MS.  Jet is "owned by" the Windows team,  ACE by the Access team.  So ACE allows the Access team to revise that flavor of the db engine as they see fit.

Answer (score 1):

As HansUp said in his comments, if your .NET app is running as 32-bit then you already have 32-bit Jet installed as part of Windows, and if your .NET app is running as 64-bit then you need the 64-bit version of the Access Database Engine (ACE) to manipulate Jet .mdb databases.

I think you also read too much into the advisory on the download page you cited in your question. It says:

> The Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable is not intended ... To be used by a system service or server-side program where the code will run under a system account, or will deal with multiple users identities concurrently, or is highly reentrant and expects stateless behavior. Examples would include ... a program called from server-side web application such as ASP.NET.

Note that the reference is to ASP.NET, not .NET in general.